# Human lying on a cooled mat - ballpark estimate of heat transfer rate

Tags: thermal-conduction

Hardware builder and youtuber Naomi Wu [came up with this idea](https://nitter.net/RealSexyCyborg/status/1548948498157998080#m) to help people with acute heat stress due to very hot and possibly moist weather: Instead of cooling all the air in a room, just place the person on a mat filled with cooled water. The idea is that this could be more efficient and be built more cheap than an AC. The thermal energy could be dissipated underground.

Would it work? Depends on the temperatures involved. Is it a good idea? I don't know, one has to look at the numbers. The idea is certainly good enough to do that!

A human at rest generates about 60 watts in thermal energy (at least that's typical ballpark). Ideally, the persons temperature should be around 37°C. Heat transfer is described by a relation of the shape $Q = A * U * \Delta T$. What are realistic values for U and A for resting person? Absent empirical data, How would one guesstimate a U value for this scenario?

Why is this relevant? Depending on the U Value, one may need low temperature in the mat to draw enough heat from a person. The lower this temperature is, the harder it may be to achieve  with passive methods like a ground coil.

(I've provided a nitter link because I find twitter unreadable without an account, but YMMV and you can simply replace nitter.net with twitter.com)

Comment: why not place the person in a tub of cold water?

Comment: @jsotola Maybe not portable enough?

Comment: If fresh water is not available in sufficient quantities, a household has only one tub or not even that but several old or otherwise at risk persons, if someone is frail and cant reliable get out of the tub, if someone wants to sleep (dangerous in a bathtub), if a solution for a long heatwave or possibly the monsoon season is needed ... a bathtub solves different problem @jsotola

Comment: Anecdotally, there is merit in the idea. Some time ago when I was living in a tropical climate I had a double bed sized water bed to sleep on for several months. The water heater was turned off & the water in the mattress was a ambient room temperature. There was no air conditioning. I found it too cold to sleep on the water bed with just a sheet between me & the mattress. It only became comfortable after I placed a blanket between the mattress & the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly an average person's skin surface is 1.5-2 m^2.
We could assume 1/3 of this will be in contact with the mat of water.

The average skin temperature is 31 to 33 celsius, except for some small areas near the eyes and armpits, etc.

There are infra-red cameras that measure skin temperatures exactly.

However, these data will change as the cold temperature of the mat penetrates the body of the subject and reduces the $\Delta T$.

'

[image: med-hotdotcom]

Comment: I wonder if we simply treat the mat as a heat exchanger, only look at thermal transmission within and treat the outside (contact surface to the person) as a constant 31° C (minus a safety factor), how far off the base we'd be.

Comment: Hardly, the body has a complex system of heat control. it weill change the blood circulation and constraint the heat flow if it senses anything wrong. I would imagine studies have been done about this subject.

Comment: But the purpose of this heat control is to keep the body at the right temperature, reactions to heat include sweating and more bloodflow to the skin and extremities.

Answer (score 0):

From the Nature article cited below:

"The thermal conductivity and thickness of skin are 0.187 W/(m·K) and 6 mm, respectively."

Nie, S., Zhang, C. & Song, J. Thermal management of epidermal electronic devices/skin system considering insensible sweating. Sci Rep 8, 14121 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-018-32152-4

As a first order approximation of U, you can use thermal conductivity divided by the thickness (characteristic length), which is based on the method of summing the resistances to conductive heat transfer to determine the overall heat transfer coefficient (i.e. 1/U = 1/h1 + L/k + 1/h2 + ...).